# disable table row in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have table with input=text fields, and when some of fields has id 'four' I need to disable this whole row. For this I try to use this function:

```
  $scope.disableIfRowHasFour = function(row){
    var result = row.filter(function(field){
      return field.id === 'four';
    })

    return result.length !== 0;
  };
```

and in html:

```
<tr ng-disabled='disableIfRowHasFour(row)' ng-repeat='row in tableFields'>
  <td ng-repeat='field in row'>
    <input type="text" value='{{field.value}}'>
  </td>
</tr>
```

and in devtools I see that row is disabled, but inputs in this row - not.

```
<tr ng-disabled="disableIfRowHasFour(row)" ng-repeat="row in tableFields" class="ng-scope" disabled="disabled">
```

where I'm wrong? I expect that all items in a row will be disabled..[Plnkr example](http://plnkr.co/edit/Ilz2iVjEqcV41XtdfIeG?p=preview)

Comment: You should add the ng-disabled tag on the input instead of the tr

Comment: yes, but how can I disabled all fields in a row, if id=four has only 1 input?

Comment: add ng-disabled='disableIfRowHasFour(row)' on the input. It should work

Comment: oh!))  you right) thx a lot

Comment: Look my answer, you can use ng-init to prevent multiple calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `tr` tag use ng-init to initialize a variable with disabled value:

```
<tr ng-init='rowDisabled=disableIfRowHasFour(row)' ng-repeat='row in tableFields'>
```

And in the inputs you add `ng-disabled`:

```
<input type="text" value='{{field.value}}' ng-disabled="rowDisabled">
```

Comment: I think this wouldn't work because rowDisabled would be a variable shared among all the rows and therefore it would be true if the last one has four and false if the last one has something different than four. But, I'm not sure about the scope of the variable.

Comment: each element in ng-repeat has its own scope, hence it will work

Comment: yes, it works too, thx! is this faster then "ng-disabled='disableIfRowHasFour(row)' on the input"? or it does no matter?

Comment: Storing the value in a variable prevent you to invoke the `disableIfRowHasFour` function on each input, saving processing.